# How to change Resource of ImageView in ListView which is set to a SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sql, listview, imageview, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to make an HighscoreList for my App. 
This List is based on a SQL Database. Save the name and the score is working very well.
The ListView is based on this row xml File:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/NAME_CELL"
         android:layout_width="250dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="20dip" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/SCORE_CELL"
         android:layout_width="20dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:textSize="20dip" />

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/PICTURE_CELL"
         android:layout_width="50dip"
         android:layout_height="20dip" 
         android:src="@drawable/no_picture" />
```

And I want that for example if the player reaches a score of 10 the PICTURE_CELL ImageView should show an Image.
For now I have a Cursor which is going through the Database and looks for the Highscores:

```
public void drawPictures() 
    {       
        if (dbCursor.moveToFirst()) {      
            do 
            {
                                if(dbCursor.getInt(2)<=4)
                {
                            Log.d(TAG, "no picture");



                }
                else if((dbCursor.getInt(2) > 4) && (dbCursor.getInt(2) <= 9))
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "picture1");


                }

                else if((dbCursor.getInt(2) > 9) && (dbCursor.getInt(2) <= 19))
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "picture2");
                }

                else if(dbCursor.getInt(2) > 20)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "picture3");
                }
            }
            while (dbCursor.moveToNext());
```

But I have no Idea how I can change the Resource of every ImageView in each row.
Please help me, this is killing me for days!

Thanks!

Comment: you should really avoid messages like "dbCursor.getInt(2)" this is not good practice. Instead of two, you should have a String Constant that i exposed from your database helper that identifies the row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully follow your `drawPictures` method but I would suggest you make your query include an `ORDER` keyword so your values are ordered rather than searching.

Then in the adapter `getView` method use `getCursor().getInt(<score column>)` and check if the score is greater than 10

```
if(score > 10)
```

If it is you can do:

```
ImageView imageView = ( ImageView ) view.findViewById( R.id.PICTURE_CELL )
```

then call:

```
// where drawable is whatever image you would like to present
imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)
```

**UPDATE** from comments

Your `SimpleCursorAdapter` is a sublcass of CursorAdapter which does have `getView`, you just need to extend your SimpleCursorAdapter and add the method below.

You need to over ride this methods like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int score = dbCursor.getInt(<score column>)
    // You might need to call moveToPosition(position) or maybe you should use getItem(position) I have not tested it
    if(score > 10) {
        ImageView imageView = ( ImageView ) view.findViewById( R.id.PICTURE_CELL )
        // where drawable is whatever image you would like to present
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no getView Method ... 
my simpleCursorAdapter looks like this:

Comment: I have no getView Method ... 
my simpleCursorAdapter looks like this:

    String[] text = new String[] {highscoreDBAdapter.KEY_PLAYERNAME, highscoreDBAdapter.KEY_SCORE};
    int [] where = new int[] {R.id.NAME_CELL, R.id.SCORE_CELL};
    sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, dbCursor, text, where);

Comment: I don't understand how I have to put the getView() Method and my Adapter together.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't explicit you need to Override SimpleCursorAdapter and just the `getView` method

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom adapter to do this kind of processing. A simple cursor will not do that for you.

Sample:
http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/

While this example uses an ArrayAdapter, it doesn't matter that much to the processs. The process s the same. You **must** create your own custom adapter. Once you create your custom cursor class, then you will override the getView(...) method with your preprocessing logic.

**Explanation of comment**

In your database helper:

```
public static final int COL_NAME = 2;
```

In your code,

```
dbCursor.getInt([Database Helper Object].COL_NAME)
```